# Output data without duplicates by maximum date

Tags: sql

I have two tables: Test1 and Test2.

Test1:

| Cat | Dog | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123412 | 1111111 | 2023-01-01 12:01:01 |
| 123412 | 2222222 | 2023-01-01 13:02:01 |

Test2

| Cat | Parrot | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123412 | 1412111 | 2023-01-01 14:01:01 |
| 123412 | 2242222 | 2023-01-01 15:02:01 |

The script for joining these tables looks like this:

```sql
select 

test1.cat
test2.cat

from Test1 test1

left join Test2 test2 on test2.cat=test1.cat
```

It is necessary to make sure that only 1 cat is displayed for the maximum date (without duplicates). Using a **subquery** or conditions inside a **JOIN** or **WHERE**.

I tried to do this subquery:

```sql
select 

test1.cat
test2.cat

from Test1 test1

left join Test2 test2 on test2.cat=test1.cat 

and test2.date = (select max(test2.date) from Test2) 

where test1.date = (select max(test1.date) from Test1)
```

but nothing happened, it displays emptiness

I apologize if my explanations are unclear

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the *desired output* based on the tables you included.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT Cat,MAX(date) as maxDate
FROM (
   SELECT test1.cat, test1.date
   FROM   Test1 test1
   UNION
   SELECT test2.cat, test2.date
   FROM   Test1 test2
)
GROUP BY Cat
```